# What is the reason that my game board element can not be displayed in my html file?

Tags: angular, ngfor, angular11

I have a loop in my Angular `html` file:

```html
    <div class="board" #board>
              <div class="row" *ngFor="let row of this.board; let i = index">
                <div *ngFor="let box of row; let j = index" id="columns">
                  <div
                    class="cell"
                    [style.backgroundColor]="box.color"
                    #cell
                    (mouseleave)="resetElement(cell)"
                    (mouseover)="
                      hoveredElement(
                        cell.getBoundingClientRect(),
                        'cell',
                        j,
                        i,
                        cell
                      )
                    "
                    (click)="deployShip(j, i)"
                  ></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

And in my `ts` file there is declared object `board` as follows:

```js
    export class GameDeployShips implements OnInit {
      public board: BoardCell[][];
    
      constructor(
        private auth: AuthService,
        private signalRService: SignalRService,
        private game: GameService
      ) {
        this.board = this.getEmptyBoard();
      }
    
    public getEmptyBoard(): BoardCell[][] {
        let board: BoardCell[][] = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          board[i] = [];
          for (let j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
            board[i][j] = {
              row: j,
              col: i,
              value: 0,
              color: 'rgba(0, 162, 255, 0.2)',
            } as BoardCell;
          }
        }
    
        return board;
      }
```

The problem is, that when running my Angular application I am getting an console error:

> ERROR Error: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object
> HTMLDivElement]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to
> Iterables such as Arrays.

```
Angular 26
    RxJS 5
    Angular 19
    RxJS 18
    ngOnInit game-play.component.ts:54
    Angular 22
    RxJS 5
    Angular 19
    RxJS 14
core.js:4610
    Angular 15
    RxJS 5
    Angular 19
    RxJS 18
    ngOnInit game-play.component.ts:54
    Angular 22
    RxJS 5
    Angular 19
    RxJS 17
    Angular 5
```

The funny thing is, that in my spike/trial application the same syntax works fine. Things I already tried:

- in `html` file using `this.board` without `this` keyword,
- in `html` file complete removing of `<div class="board" #board>` gived no errors in console,
- in `html` file replacing `this.board` with `getEmptyBoard()`: `<div class="row" *ngFor="let row of this.board; let i = index">` draws the board, but it is not the way I wanted to do it,
- changing `div` to `ng-template`:

  `<ng-template class="row" *ngFor="let row of this.board; let i = index">`
  `<ng-template *ngFor="let box of row; let j = index" id="columns">`
- changing `board` and `getEmptyBoard()` types to `any`

I try to figure out this already a few hours. I will appreciate any help and clues with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it :)))

I don't know why angular don't like `board` name.
just rename it to `_board` or something else

See Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-qdw5fm

Comment: Thanks for writing, but in my question I mentioned that I tried this already.

Comment: After your edition, we have a winner :) Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`<div class="board" #board>` creates a reference called `board` using the `#` operator. The varialbe used in the `ngFor` is then referencing the `div` and not the value of the component. Renaming one of both will solve the issue.